# R: selecting items matching criteria from a vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector in R, which consists of both negative and positive numbers. I want to separate the numbers in the list based on sign (ignoring zero for now), into two seperate lists:

- a new vector containing only the negative numbers
- another vector containing only the positive numbers

The documentation shows how to do this for selecting rows/columns/cells in a dataframe - but this dosen't work with vectors AFAICT.

How can it be done (without a for loop)?

Comment: Turns out, I can simply use the name of the vector in the selection criteria. For eg: negs <- temp[temp <0]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is done very easily (added check for NaN):

```
d <- c(1, -1, 3, -2, 0, NaN)

positives <- d[d>0 & !is.nan(d)]
negatives <- d[d<0 & !is.nan(d)]
```

If you want exclude both NA and NaN, is.na() returns true for both:

```
d <- c(1, -1, 3, -2, 0, NaN, NA)

positives <- d[d>0 & !is.na(d)]
negatives <- d[d<0 & !is.na(d)]
```

Comment: how do I ignore NaNs from the selection?

Comment: I've edited the answer.  Note that d>0 is a vector of mode logical, same for is.nan(d) and is.na(d).  Applying & to two vectors of mode logical does the "logical" thing.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using "square brackets".
A new vector is created which contains those values which are greater than zero. Since a comparison operator is used, it will denote values in Boolean. Hence square brackets are used to get the exact numeric value.

```
d_vector<-(1,2,3,-1,-2,-3)
new_vector<-d_vector>0 
pos_vector<-d_vector[new_vector]
new1_vector<-d_vector<0
neg_vector<-d_vector[new1_vector]
```

Answer (score 1):

`purrr`package includes some useful functions for filtering vectors:

```
library(purrr)
test_vector <- c(-5, 7, 0, 5, -8, 12, 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, NA, Inf, -Inf, NaN)

positive_vector <- keep(test_vector, function(x) x > 0)
positive_vector
# [1]   7   5  12   1   2   3 Inf

negative_vector <- keep(test_vector, function(x) x < 0)
negative_vector
# [1]   -5   -8   -1   -2   -3 -Inf
```

You can use also `discard` function